# How to select binding with no host header using Get-WebBinding

Tags: powershell, iis

I have the following bindings:

[image]

I can select the binding which has the host header `api` like so:

[image]

However, I cannot select the binding which has no host header.  If I pass in `""` or `$NUL`, I still get all bindings:

[image]

One possible solution I've found is to filter the list using `Where-Object`, like so:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this which will get me the default binding with no host header and nothing else?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really looks like you can't explicitly use `Get-WebBinding` to get *just* the one with no Host Header.

`Get-WebBinding` returns all bindings. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webbinding?view=winserver2012-ps), our only available parameters for filtering are:

- `-Name` - We are already using to specify website name
- `-IPAddress` - N/A in this case
- `-Port` - can only really specify 443 which won't help
- `-Protocol` - can only specify https which won't help
- `-HostHeader` - our best hope - Let's investigate.

Our only option is to use `-HostHeader`. We know it accepts a type `string`, so we can try all tools in our toolbox:

```
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -HostHeader ""
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -HostHeader $null
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -HostHeader ([String]::Empty)
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -HostHeader "*"
```

They return all the same entries:

```
protocol bindingInformation sslFlags
-------- ------------------ --------
https    *:443:api          1
https    *:443:api.cluster  1
https    *:443:             0
```

i.e. all of them. This makes sense because the `-HostHeader` parameter is a *wildcard Filter*. We can only *filter* entries and not *select* entries. An "Empty" filter (i.e. "", `$null`, `[String]::Empty`) is the same as returning everything (i.e. that's why it returned the same as the full wildcard `"*"`).

We can prove this by changing the filter to:

```
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -HostHeader "api*"
```

Which returns:

```
protocol bindingInformation sslFlags
-------- ------------------ --------
https    *:443:api          1
https    *:443:api.cluster  1
```

The exact opposite of what we want.

Since `Get-WebBinding` only has filtering parameters, we need to combine it with a selection parameter like `Where-Object`. Since `sslflags` is the flag for "Require Server Name Indication", the "better" way is to select based on the `bindingInformation`:

```
Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" | Where-Object { $_.bindingInformation -eq '*:443:' }
```

Returning what we want:

```
protocol bindingInformation sslFlags
-------- ------------------ --------
https    *:443:             0
```

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure you're 100% correct.  Only workaround is some sort of `Where-Object` filter..

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but for the benefit of others that search and find this thread. Try this

`(Get-WebBinding).BindingInformation | ? {$_ -like '*:'}`